# php Need to Alter Second Occurrence of Substring in a String

Tags: php

Is there a way to find all instances of a substring in a string. This is what I have so far but it seems when I search for the 'ed' substring it stops looking when it finds the first one. Thus, the word 'hedged' is unaffected when I try to alter the ending.

```
<?php

$wordList2 = array('kissed','hoped','learned','wanted','sounded', 'hedged');

for ($i = 0; $i<sizeof($wordList2);$i++){
    $wrongAnswers2[$wordList2[$i]] = array();
}

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($wordList2); $i++){

    if(strpos($wordList2[$i], 'ed')===(strlen($wordList2[$i])-2)) {


    $pos = strpos($wordList2[$i], 'ed');
    if(
    substr($wordList2[$i], -3, 1) ==='p' || 
    substr($wordList2[$i], -3, 1) ==='f' ||
    substr($wordList2[$i], -3, 1) ==='s' ||
    substr($wordList2[$i], -3, 1) ==='k' ||
    substr($wordList2[$i], -3, 1) ==='h' 
    ){
        $replacement = substr_replace($wordList2[$i], 't', $pos,2);
        array_push($wrongAnswers2[$wordList2[$i]],$replacement);
    } else if   
    (
    substr($wordList2[$i], -3, 1) ==='b' || 
    substr($wordList2[$i], -3, 1) ==='v' ||
    substr($wordList2[$i], -3, 1) ==='z' ||
    substr($wordList2[$i], -3, 1) ==='g' ||
    substr($wordList2[$i], -3, 1) ==='n' 
    ){
        $replacement = substr_replace($wordList2[$i], 'd', $pos,2);
        array_push($wrongAnswers2[$wordList2[$i]],$replacement);
    } else if   
    (
    substr($wordList2[$i], -3, 1) ==='d' || 
    substr($wordList2[$i], -3, 1) ==='t' 
    ){
        $replacement = substr_replace($wordList2[$i], 'id', $pos);
        array_push($wrongAnswers2[$wordList2[$i]],$replacement);
    }

} 
}
?>
```

This is the output I get. I basically want a way to make the programme alter the ending of 'hedged'. Thanks.

```
   Array
(
[kissed] => Array
    (
        [0] => kisst
    )

[hoped] => Array
    (
        [0] => hopt
    )

[learned] => Array
    (
        [0] => learnd
    )

[wanted] => Array
    (
        [0] => wantid
    )

[sounded] => Array
    (
        [0] => soundid
    )

[hedged] => Array
    (
    )
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific requirement you could use strrpos instead of strpos - it's the same thing except it finds the last occurrence of the substring rather than the first.

Comment: Thanks! I must have overlooked that when browsing the manual! Very useful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just altered the opening IF condition and adjusted the $pos variable:

```
if((strlen($wordList2[$i]) - strrpos($wordList2[$i], 'ed'))===2) {


    $pos = strrpos($wordList2[$i], 'ed');

...etc.
```

Works much better now, thanks moopet.